# Как по клику сравнить класс и свойство массива?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Подскажите как при клике по классу, сравнивать id, и вытаскивать нужное значение из data.js?

```
                    <div class="qwer">
                        <img id="htmlInfo" src="./src/img/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.png" alt=" " />
                    </div>

                    <div class="qwer ">
                        <img id="cssInfo " src="./src/img/css3-logo.png " alt=" " />
                    </div>
                    <div class="qwer ">
                        <img id="jsInfo " src="./src/img/js-logo.png " alt=" " />
                    </div>
```

data.js

```
const data = {

properties: [

    { "id": "htmlInfo", "skillsOne": "АДАПТИВНАЯ ВЕРСТКА", "skillsTwo": "КРОССБРАУЗЕРНАЯ ВЕРСТКА", "skillsThree": "CODE CONVENTION", "img": "http://fdk-developer/src/img/1200px-black.png" },
    { "id": "cssInfo", "skillsOne": "АНИМАЦИЯ", "skillsTwo": "TRANSFORM", "skillsThree": "ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЙ ДИЗАЙН" },
    { "id": "jsInfo", "skillsOne": "ASDASDASD", "skillsTwo": "DSADASDAD", "skillsThree": "ОSADASDASНАЛЬНЫЙ ДИЗАЙН" }, ]}
```

Пробвал

```
let qwer = document.querySelectorAll(".qwer img");


 for (let i = 0; i < qwer.length; i++) {

qwer[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    for (let x = 0; x < data.properties.length; x++) {



         if (qwer[i].id == data.properties[x].id) {
          console.log(data.properties[x].skillsOne);

    }
})
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код работает, но отчасти. У Вас в HTML после id идет пробел, который учитывается при сравнении его с id из таблицы.
Нужно просто добавить `.trim()` для id элемента.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".qwer img").map(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let item = data.properties.find(d => (e.id.trim() == d.id));
        console.log(item.skillsOne);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

и дальше делаешь со своим объектом всё что тебе нужно

```js
const properties = [

  {
    "id": "htmlInfo",
    "skillsOne": "АДАПТИВНАЯ ВЕРСТКА",
    "skillsTwo": "КРОССБРАУЗЕРНАЯ ВЕРСТКА",
    "skillsThree": "CODE CONVENTION",
    "img": "http://fdk-developer/src/img/1200px-black.png"
  },
  {
    "id": "cssInfo",
    "skillsOne": "АНИМАЦИЯ",
    "skillsTwo": "TRANSFORM",
    "skillsThree": "ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЙ ДИЗАЙН"
  },
  {
    "id": "jsInfo",
    "skillsOne": "ASDASDASD",
    "skillsTwo": "DSADASDAD",
    "skillsThree": "ОSADASDASНАЛЬНЫЙ ДИЗАЙН"
  },
]

$('.qwer img').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('id');
  let [data] = properties.filter(el => el['id'] === id);
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qwer">
  <img id="htmlInfo" src="./src/img/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.png" alt=" " />
</div>

<div class="qwer ">
  <img id="cssInfo" src="./src/img/css3-logo.png " alt=" " />
</div>
<div class="qwer ">
  <img id="jsInfo" src="./src/img/js-logo.png " alt=" " />
</div>
```